# Why are PyCharm and Pylance not detecting packages installed in editable mode?

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, pip, pycharm, vscode-python

Recently, code analysis tools like PyCharm and Pylance in VSCode are not picking up packages installed in editable mode (`pip install -e <package_name>`).

This made it so I could not navigate to imported modules by Ctrl-clicking (in VSCode), and it is not providing me docstrings for imported functions.

I noticed that where in my `site_packages` directory there used to be a file with the package's name, now there is only a file called `__editable_package_name_finder.py` instead.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`setuptools` has changed the way it carries out editable installs which seems to have broken compatibility with various tools. For an in-depth explanation of the behavior refer to [this page](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/development_mode.html).

Setuptools provides a config option to stick to the old installation method.
Either by setting the following flag on install:
`pip install -e . --config-settings editable_mode=compat`

Or by setting the environment variable `SETUPTOOLS_ENABLE_FEATURES="legacy-editable"` before installing, though this last method has the limtation explained in the note [here](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/development_mode.html#legacy-behavior):

> Newer versions of pip no longer run the fallback command python setup.py develop when the pyproject.toml file is present. This means that setting the environment variable SETUPTOOLS_ENABLE_FEATURES="legacy-editable" will have no effect when installing a package with pip.

After reinstalling the desired package using legacy mode, you will probably need to either restart the editor, or in the case of VSCode run the command "Python: Restart language server" in <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>

Comment: Wish I could give this more than one up vote.